# Unable to line up 2 objects in the same line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to line up  two objects i.e. Text box and a search box in the same line but for some reason its not lining up. Tried several tutorial but still no go. As far as I know I am missing something. Any help is appreciated. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.transbox {
            background-color: grey;
            border: 1px solid black;
            opacity:0.6;
            filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            padding: 5%;
        }
        div.transbox pt {
            border: 1px solid #505050; /*#123360;*/
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 27%;
            background-color: white;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -khtml-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            border-radius:10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        div.transbox ps {
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            border: 1px solid #505050; /*#123360;*/
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 27%;
            background-color: white;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -khtml-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            border-radius:10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            padding: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="transbox">
        <pt> example.com</pt>
        <ps><form>
            <input type="text" name="search" />
        </form> </ps>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the difference between: Text box and a search box? I may be tired, but `<pt>` and `<ps>` aren't valid tags.

Comment: You can't just invent new HTML elements.  `<pt>` and `<ps>`? Invalid HTML will never behave predictably.

Comment: I won't repeat the earlier comments, but aside from that this is generally something handled by a simple float:left.

Comment: Sorry for the ps and pt tags. It seems to work fine therefore I didn't change. Anyways float:left and right  worked for me. Thanks Raskolnikov.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<pt>` and `<ps>` are *not* valid tags.

I have made a standards-compliant, working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/7LXQ9/.

**Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.transbox {
            background-color: grey;
            border: 1px solid black;
            opacity:0.6;
            filter:alpha(opacity=60); /* For IE8 and earlier */
            padding: 5%;
        }
        div.transbox #site-name {
            border: 1px solid #505050; /*#123360;*/
            position: relative;
            left: 0;
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 27%;
            background-color: white;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -khtml-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            border-radius:10px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        div.transbox form {
            display: inline-block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            border: 1px solid #505050; /*#123360;*/
            font-size: 12px;
            width: 27%;
            background-color: white;
            border-radius:10px;
            -moz-border-radius:3px;
            -webkit-border-radius:3px;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: black;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        div.transbox input {
            appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="transbox">
        <span id="site-name">example.com</span>
        <form>
            <input type="search" name="search" />
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

By the way, the `input` type `search` was added with [HTML5](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/HTML5).